# Passing a JavaScript Array to A PHP Class Via AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing JavaScript Array To PHP Through JQuery $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013728/passing-javascript-array-to-php-through-jquery-ajax)

Can I pass an array to a php file through JavaScript using AJAX?  In my application code 
JavaScript builds the parameters based on user input, and then an AJAX call is made to a processing script.

For example, if the processing script url was process_this.php the call made from JavaScript would be `process_this.php?handler=some_handler&param1=p1&param2=p2&param3=p3`

Could I do something like this?:

```
process_this.php?handler=some_handler&param1=[array]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

using JQUERY you could do something like this

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var jsarr = new Array('param1', 'param2', 'param3');

    $.post("process_this.php", { params: jsarr}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });

});
</script>
```

php script

```
<?php print_r($_POST['params']); ?>
```

output would be

> Array ( [0] => param1 [1] => param2 [2] => param3 )

Answer (score 0):

What about sending an JSON Object via Post to your PHP-Script?
Have a look at this [PHP JSON Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.json.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON to encode the array to a string, send the string via HTTP request to PHP, and decode it there. You can do it also with objects.

In Javascript you do:

```
var my_array = [p1, p2, p3]; 
var my_object = {"param1": p1, "param2": p2, "param3": p3};
var json_array = JSON.stringify(my_array);    
var json_object = JSON.stringify(my_object);    
var URL = "process_this.php?handler=some_handler" +
          "&my_array=" + json_array + "&my_object=" + json_object;
```

In PHP you do:

```
$my_array = json_decode($_POST['my_array'])); 
$my_object = json_decode($_POST['my_object']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send a json object to your php , thats the standard approach