# Javascript array to php with jQuery ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing JavaScript Array To PHP Through JQuery $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013728/passing-javascript-array-to-php-through-jquery-ajax)

I'm trying to pass some variables gathered from n dynamically generated inputs to php with ajax.

```
<input type="text" class="big" id="service" name="service[]" maxlenght="100"/>
```

This is the dynamically generated input(there could be 1 or 100).
Now, if I submit them without ajax it gives me an array in php by simply doing

```
$services = $_POST['service'];
```

But what if I want to do it with ajax without refreshing the page?

```
var action = $("form_act").attr('action');
var form_data = {
    service: $("#service").val(),
    ajax_request: 1
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: action,
    data: form_data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        if (response.error == 'none')
            $("#form_content").slideToggle('slow', function () {
                $('#form_content').load('includes/db_setup_form.php');
                $("#form_content").delay(500).slideToggle('slow');
            });
        else {

            $("#ajax_response").html("<p>" + response.msg + "</p>");

        }
    }
});
```

It only sends the first service variable and not a complete array with the others(if there are) variables.  Any suggestions?

Comment: already read that but i'm not sure on how to proceed on this case since i've more than 1 variable to send(in the above code i only included the array i need to pass, but i've more inputs to send).

Comment: This should be helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you  problem that selector ('#services') takes only first input value. You should remove id and just serialize form as below.

If all you need to pass is all values from form you can use

```
data: $('form#my-form').serialize() // this code puts all of the inputs into passable and readable for PHP, way.
```

And then in $_POST['service'] will be an array of inputs values.

For example:

```
<form action="save.php" method="post" id="services">
    <input type="text" name="service[0]" value="1st Service" />
    <input type="text" name="service[1]" value="2nd Service" />
    <input type="text" name="service[2]" value="3rd Service" />
    <input type="text" name="service[..]" value=".. Service" />
    <input type="text" name="service[N]" value="N Service" />
</form>
```

In your JS:

```
$.post($('form#services').attr('action'), $('form#services').serialize(), function(response) {});
```

And then in save.php you can get an array in $_POST:

```
var_dump($_POST['service']);
```

Hope that's is exactly what you need.

Comment: What if i'd like to send another variable(ajax_request) together with those from the form?
Thanks

Comment: Tried `data: $('form#invoice_form').serialize(), ajax_request:1,` but it didn't work

Comment: $('form#invoice_form').serialize() + '&ajax_request=1'; Maybe...) .serialize() return url-encoded string, so you can append pairs key-value to this string by adding &key=value.

Answer (score 2):

You should select the inputs by `name` attribute because it is invalid to have more than one element with the same ID in an HTML document. Your jQuery selector knows it's looking for what should be a unique element so it stops after it finds the first one. Also the `.val()` function only finds the value of the first element in the set of elements selected.

Here is what I would change:

```
var form_data = {
    service: $("#service").val(),
    ajax_request: 1
   };
```

To:

```
var form_data = {
    service: $('[name="service[]"]').serialize(),
    ajax_request: 1
   };
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sS7YP/

Here is the documentation for `.serialize()`: http://api.jquery.com/serialize

Comment: This looks promising, i'm gonna test it as soon as possible. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A solution which creates a clean array of the values of your `service[]` inputs, using [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).

```
var $form = $('#form_id'),
    $inputs = $form.find('input[name^=service]'); // Do not select by ID

$form.on('submit', function(event) {
    // Build an array only containing the services values
    var values = [];
    $.map($inputs, function(e) {
        values.push(e.value);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eTU2y/1/