# Post Variable and Array from JQuery to PHP in same $ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have arrays and variables in JQuery and I want to know that Can I POST both arrays and variables from single $ajax jquery request to my php page. If yes then How will I post data from Jquery and how will i handle in PHP page.

```
var get_id = [], get_product= [];  //Array
    var day = $("#day").val();  // Variable
    var month = $("#month").val(); // Variable
    var year = $("#year").val();   // Variable
```

Thanks

Comment: $.POST (jquery) and $_POST in php.. Or.. $.AJAX (jQuery) and either $_POST or $_GET according to your preferences.

Comment: your answer is correct for only variables, but my question is how can i post variable and array both in single $ajax request

Comment: You can pass literally everything through ajax.. you can either pass a string, a number or an array using the same method. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013728/passing-javascript-array-to-php-through-jquery-ajax

Comment: I am getting output as **Array** text when I am using $_POST['id'];

Where `id` is an array POSTED by jquery $ajax request

Comment: Have you tried using json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send complex data types, such as arrays, it's easier to JSON encode your data, and decode it on the PHP side:

```
var data = {
    get_id : get_id,
    get_product : get_product,
    day : day,
    month : month
};

$.post('url', { data : JSON.stringify(data) }, function(response){
    // success
});
```

On the PHP side:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);

echo $data->day;
foreach($data->get_product as $p){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to encode/decode into/from JSON. Keep it simple and just post the data object as is:

```
$.ajax('/index.php', {
   type: 'POST',
   data: {
      get_id:[],
      get_product:[],
      day: $("#day").val(),
      month: $("#month").val(),
      year: $("#year").val()
   }
});
```

On the PHP side, you can see the post data:

```
var_dump($_POST); // post is a keyed (nested) array.
```