# Pass Javascript array containing objects using JQuery post

Tags: php, jquery

I have a Javascript array containing Javascript Objects:

```
var fruits = []; 

var fruit = new Object; 
fruit.name = apple; 
fruit.color = red; 

fruits.push(fruit);
```

How do I pass this using JQuery's post `$.post` so that all its contents are accessible through PHP's `$_POST` array?

How are the object properties accessed with PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing JavaScript Array To PHP Through JQuery $.ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013728/passing-javascript-array-to-php-through-jquery-ajax)

Comment: It is not a duplicate as the above mentioned question does not demonstrate how arrays containing Javascript objects should be handled. Do they need to be serialised before passing them through POST? How are they accessed with PHP's `$_POST`?

Comment: An array containing JavaScript objects?

Comment: Like the example above where `fruit ` is an object with properties

Comment: @JayBlanchard not really necessary to convert to json to send to php... can use default internal form encoding

Comment: True @charlietfl, and what you're saying is stated in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will end up with object looking like:

```
var fruit ={
  name:'Apple',
  color: 'Red'
}
```

You can simply post that object to php

```
$.post('path/to/server', fruit, function(resp){
   // validate response and do something
});
```

Default contentType for `$.ajax` of which `$.post` is a shorthand method is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so it is exactly the same as sending a form.

jQuery internals will take care of encoding the data object passed as argument to `$.ajax` or `$.post` or other shorthand methods

In PHP

```
$fruitName = $_POST['name'];
$fruitColor = $_POST['color'];
```

If you wanted to send the whole array you could do:

```
$.post(url, {fruits: fruits});
```

Then in php:

```
 $fruitsArray = $_POST['fruits'];
 foreach($fruitsArray as $item){
    $name = $item['name'];
 }
```

Comment: Your answer helped a lot. I hope this question will not be closed as I could not find on Stackoverflow details of particularly how Javascript Objects passed are accessed with PHP.