# How to Load a JavaScript Array Items To MySQL Database Using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I Have a simple array which looks like

```
var arr = ["foo", "2015/11/04", "Jill", "Smith", "60"]
var serializedArr = JSON.stringify( arr );
```

now can you please let me know how I can load the `serializedArr` into the `data` in following ajax request?

```
var upload = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "assets/.../loader.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
    }
});
```

and also how to read the `data` on server side PHP file? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing JavaScript Array To PHP Through JQuery $.ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013728/passing-javascript-array-to-php-through-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var upload = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "assets/.../loader.php",
    data: {array:serializedArr},// pass here{key:value,key:value,...}
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {
    }
});
```

In php

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['array']);
print_r($array);// this will get back the array which was encoded.
```

You have to decode the array because, array is encoded(`JSON.stringify(arr)`)

Comment: Thanks Niranjan, just on PHP side can you please let me know incase of having a variable like `$foo`  how can I get it's value from the `$array` I mean the first item in the `arr`

Comment: use `foreach()` on `$array`, and get the values .

Comment: why `foreach()`? I just need the first element? in a only one set of array

Comment: `echo $array[0];`. But this is simply spoon feeding nothing else

Comment: if you want only 1 element, then dont encode r aont use array. just send as normal variable.