# Send array with Ajax to PHP script in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to send an array from a JS file to a PHP file in the server but when I try to use the array in php, I got nothing.

This is my function in JS:

```
var sortOrder = [];
var request = function() {

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(sortOrder);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/MYPAGE.php',
        data: { sort_order : jsonString },
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
            alert('data sent');
        }
    })  
};
```

and this is my php file MYPAGE.php:

```
<?php

$arrayJobs = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['sort_order']));

echo($arrayJobs);?>
```

This is the first time that I use ajax and honestly I'm also confused about the url because I'm working on a template in wordpress.
Even if I don't use json it doesn't work!

These are the examples that I'm looking at:

[Send array with Ajax to PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001526/send-array-with-ajax-to-php-script)

[Passing JavaScript array to PHP through jQuery $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013728/passing-javascript-array-to-php-through-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Use web developer tools to view the network request. There you can view the response and the console to view errors. [Chrome extension](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=chrome+web+developer&*)

Comment: // get the raw POST data
    $rawData = file_get_contents("php://input");

    // this returns null if not valid json
   echo json_decode($rawData);

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893574/php-php-input-vs-post

Answer (score 2):

First, where is that javascript code? It needs to be in a .php file for the php code (wordpress function) to execute.

Second, how do you know that there is no data received on the back-end. You are sending an AJAX request, and not receiving the result here. If you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on `$.ajax` you'll see that the response from the server is passed to the `success` callback.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/MYPAGE.php',
    data: { sort_order : jsonString },
    cache: false,
    success: function(responseData) {
        // consider using console.log for these kind of things.
        alert("Data recived: " + responseData);
    }
})
```

You'll see whatever you `echo` from the PHP code in this alert. Only then you can say if you received nothing.

Also, `json_decode` will return a JSON object (or an array if you tell it to). You can not `echo` it out like you have done here. You should instead use `print_r` for this.

```
$request = json_decode($_POST['sort_order']);
print_r($request);
```

And I believe `sort_order` in the javascript code is empty just for this example and you are actually sending something in your actual code, right?

Comment: @squGElm thanks for replying. First, the array has elements inside. The js file is in the "template folder -> assets -> js" and the php file is in the template folder. I said I can't see nothing because when I try to print or echo  the variable in the php file it displays nothing on the page.

Comment: @M.Simon you aren't seeing anything on the page because it is an ajax request and there will be nothing in the page until you put something in there. The success callback function is called when the server responds with some data, and you can then put this data in your page however/wherever you like. If the code is in a js file, then I'm sure the php code is not being executed, try puting the URI to the php file directly in the js code for now.

Comment: When I try that in wordpress I get console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined

Comment: @5Diraptor it’s probably because you haven’t enabled jQuery to be used in your Wordpress theme. See https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Answer (score -1):

the problem is in your url, javascript cannot interprate the php tags, what I suggest to you is to pass the "get_template_directory_uri()" as a variable from the main page like that :

```
<script>
  var get_template_directory_uri = "<?php get_template_directory_uri() ?>";
</script>
```

and after, use this variable in the url property.

Good luck.

I hope it helps