# Didn't receive Value from ajax to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

At first here is my code:

HTML with Javascript:

```
function getValues(){
    var filter;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myphpfile.PHP?action=sek",
            data: "id=1",
            async: false,
            success: function(ret){
                    filter = ret;
                }
        });
    console.log(filter);
```

PHP myphpfile.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    print myfunction($_GET['action'],$_GET['id']);
}
```

My problem:
When I try to print the result out with console.log, the whole myphpfile.php is printed. 
As I know, that means that no values reached the HTML file. But Why?

The function "myfunction" have results, i have tried it first. This function returns an array. ( I can't show this function here)

I don't get it what i'm doing wrong, Please have a look, It drive me crazy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To start with you are making a `post` request with AJAX then expecting a `get` request in your function!

Comment: Move `console.log` into success callback

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013728/passing-javascript-array-to-php-through-jquery-ajax

Comment: Only 'action' will be in the GET array, not 'id'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action` is in the `$_GET` super global and `id` is in the `$_POST` super global.

PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    print myfunction($_GET['action'],$_POST['id']);
}
```

Also, you need to pass an object to your `data` parameter, not a string:

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myphpfile.PHP?action=sek",
    data: {id: "1"},
    async: false,
    success: function(ret){
            filter = ret;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change PHP File Request

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
    print myfunction($_GET['action'],$_GET['id']);
}
```

Also You can use [$_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php).

Answer (score 0):

First in Javascript:

```js
function getValues(){
    var filter;
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myphpfile.PHP?action=sek",
            data: { id: 1 },
            async: false,
            success: function(ret){
                    filter = ret;
                }
        });
    console.log(filter);
```

Afterthat you have to obtain id by $_POST['id']

Comment: ` $_POS['id'] ` Changes to `$_POST['id]`

Comment: Yes. Done, Thanks!